# how to unit test a python process

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a unit test for a python process. I want to run the process for a few seconds and then do an assert to make sure that an instance variable of that process equals to the expected value.

```
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def run():
       ......

class TestMultiProcess(unittest.TestCase):

    def testStuff(self):
        process = MyProcess()
        process.start()
        time.sleep(20)
        process.exit.set()
        process.join()

        assert(process.ivar == 42)
```

The problem is in the last line. Because it is a process not a thread, I can't get the value of ivar directly (always equals to 0). I am wondering what is the preferred way to get that ivar?

Comment: unrelated: you could use `process.exit.wait(20)` instead of `time.sleep(20)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to *unit test* a code that is run using `multiprocessing` is to test individual functions directly if possible.

To get a value from another process, you could send it: `mp.Pipe()`, `mp.Queue()` or you could use a shared value: `mp.Value()`.